# Advanced Search in the Web API?

Tags: spotify

Is there anyway to build an advanced search (artist, track, album) on the metadata Web API?

From what I gather from the docs, the API allows for either Artist/Track/Album searches but not a combination of them, even though there is an **[advanced search syntax](http://www.spotify.com/us/about/features/advanced-search-syntax/)** link in the [introduction](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/#introduction) page, under "**related topics**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually tried it? As far as I'm aware, advanced search using the syntax you linked should work just fine.